# How to use another object in templete

Tags: email-template

Can we use other `object's` field in `VF template`, if yes then how?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use another object field using a component and for this you need to make a apex controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by creating a [Visualforce Email Template](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_intro.htm) with a Custom Controller.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a Custom Controller Apex class.
2. Create a Custom Component that has its controller attribute set to the class created in step #1.
3. Create a Visualforce Email Template that includes the Custom Component created in Step #2.

This is outlined with an example in the documentation [Using Custom Controllers within Visualforce Email Templates](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm).